# Suitescript - transforming item fulfillment mark shipped

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

We utilize advanced shipping Pick, Pack, Ship and I'm having a difficult trying create an item fulfillment marked shipped.

After transforming, the item fulfillment is marked as picked.
I tried to set the value by using
`fulfillment.setValue(’shipstatus’,’ItemShip:C’);`
but that would return an error.

```
 
        var fulfillment = record.transform({
            fromType: record.Type.SALES_ORDER,
            fromId: _salesOrderId,
            toType: record.Type.ITEM_FULFILLMENT,
            defaultValues: {
                inventorylocation: 31
            },
            isDynamic:true
        })
```

Is this possible to create an item fulfillment as marked shipped when transforming?

Answer (score 1):

After you create the fulfillment you may need to set up packages and verify which and what quantity of items are being shipped. How these default is dependent on a couple of setups in your Netsuite account.

When you've got all that done you'd set the Shipped status as:

`fulfillment.setValue({fieldId:'shipstatus', value:'C'});`

The old fields on Netsuite that cause or reflect state changes on things (transactions, support cases, etc) often have puzzling values. So you search for status with values such as 'ItemShip:C' but you just set the status as 'C'.